# Is there a way to have a sum window function not progressively sum through the partition?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I try to sum the partition to get the total of each stage, it [adds progressively through the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGEgJ.png) of the partition instead.

```
select
        sub_business,
        channel,
        stage,
        time::date                                                                     as time,
        count(session_id)                                                              as count,
        count / lag(count) over (partition by time::date, channel order by count desc) as conversion_rate,
        sum(count) over (partition by stage, time::date order by count)                as total
    from
        loan_dw_test.marketing.uploan_funnel_table
    where
          time::date = '2019-06-21'
      and stage in ('application_view', 'lead')
    group by
        time::date,
        sub_business,
        channel,
        stage
    order by
        time  desc,
        sub_business,
        channel,
        count desc
```

For example I'd want to get the total of 57 for all application_view rows and 62 for all lead rows.

Comment: Look up frame specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to calculate sum per entire partition you could skip `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT  ...
       ,sum(count) over (partition by stage, time::date)
FROM ...
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'm still learning window functions and was using lag before which required the order by. That did the trick!!

Comment: @geoff Great to hear that :) [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Waiting to. There's a 10 min window before I can and you were too fast at answering the question!